# AudioKit Listener/Notification when input/output has changed from OS?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

When connecting to a bluetooth headset (Airpods in my case), `AudioKit` crashes while running. This is due to a sample rate mismatch. Is there any type of notification, I can observe that when a user changes an input device with a different sample rate, I can safely change `AudioKit's` sample rate without causing a crash?

Comment: same problem here. have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi HTron, I have *not* found a solution yet, but haven't really had time to explore, I'll update this thread with any news as I find it.